# Will the pro trinket gamepad library work on an Arduino Uno?

Tags: arduino-uno, atmega328

I have an Arduino Uno and I wanted to know if the pro trinket gamepad library works on an Arduino Uno since both have same atmega328p CPU chip.

Comment: why don't you try it? ... then ask a question about any problem that you encounter

Comment: I’m not familiar with the pro trinket device (https://learn.adafruit.com/introducing-pro-trinket/pinouts?view=all) but looking at the library (https://github.com/buxit/Pro_Trinket_USB_Gamepad) readme says it is an Arduino library. I suspect it would come down to checking pins and peripherals to decide whether it will work on Uno. @jsotola’s suggestion is practical, why not try it and see? I’d put my money on your having a reasonable chance of success.

Answer (score 4):

The Pro Trinket has a USB connector wired to the ATmega328P, and the
Pro_Trinket_USB_Gamepad library uses this connection to impersonate a
USB gamepad.

The Arduino Uno also has a USB connector, but it is *not* wired to the
ATmega328P. It is instead connected to an auxiliary chip (an ATmega16U2)
which serves exclusively as a USB-to-serial converter. Since your
sketches run on the 328P, and the 328P has no access to the USB port,
you cannot use this library on the Uno.

Well, actually you may be able to use the library if add an extra USB
connector, and link it to the 328P. See how it is done in the [schematic
of the Pro Trinket 5V](https://cdn-learn.adafruit.com/assets/assets/000/018/948/original/adafruit_products_protrink5vschm.png). Beware of the 3.6V Zener diodes:
these are needed to avoid damaging the serial port of your computer.